# The "electrical" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-cleanup

I got thinking, and the [electrical](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical) tag is pretty dumb. What's everyone think about nuking, banning, and retagging the affected questions? There are 197 at the moment, 30 of which are single tag.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty dumb.  We should get rid of them all and replace them with the "question" tag.

Comment: That's going to leave a lot of untagged questions

Comment: @Passerby What's worse, a stupid, meaningless tag, or having to go through a re-tag some questions?

Comment: Considering there's a bunch currently untagged, including year old questions, maybe deal with those first instead of adding another what, 30? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/untagged

Comment: Given that the site has both "electrical" and "electronics" in the name, it's pretty much implied that any on-topic question here is already about something vaguely electrical. So the [electrical] tag doesn't really seem to add any value.

Comment: @Passerby most of those [untagged] questions are downvoted/low quality, but I agree with tagging the useful questions.

Comment: Just flagged most of those as "Per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225586/allow-10k-to-vote-to-delete-on-locked-rejected-migrations please delete this negative score, unanswered, closed, rejected migration question. It's crudding up the place."

Comment: Because we try to migrate a lot of stuff out -__-, when those get rejected, the system Locks the questions, and prevents them from being auto deleted like normally crap questions get deleted. And that's just the ones in the [tag:untagged] tag, who knows how many other exist

Comment: @MattYoung sorry, didn't mean to hijack your question...

Comment: @MarkU No matter, I think we got some positive actions going as a result.

Comment: Per @MarkU's observation, maybe we could change the software to tag every question "electrical".  I like uniformity :)

Comment: In the UK it's a pretty common distinction to use "electrical" to mean higher voltage and/or power (ususally mains AC, but also automotive 12V and 24V, DC links etc.) engineering and "electronic" to mean small-signal and low-power engineering. The tag makes sense to me in that context, but I've realised recently that that distinction isn't international.

Comment: @xcodo we have a tag for mains and high voltage already. See the related questions in the side for the clean up on that

Comment: I'll ask for a tag wipe on Monday, barring any compelling counter argument.

Comment: @W5VO It's Friday and the tag's still here. Any update on this?

Comment: @MattYoung Sorry, I've been pretty busy. I haven't asked yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Are you damn sure about destroying electical?]

I was. I also blacklisted the tag. Please look over [untagged questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) to provide correct tags or vote to delete.

Answer (score 11):

I'm in favor of removing it. While one could argue that we do allow non-electrical questions (signal/control theory, embedded programming, HDL, history...), all of those subjects are on-topic because of their relation to electricity and *electrical* engineering. Also, there are far more electrical questions than any other kind. Looking at the front page right now, I see one programming question, one control theory question, one pure digital question, and 47 "electrical" questions. A tag that applies to ~95% of our questions does not seem very useful.

Comment: In some parts of the world a distinction is made between *electronic* engineering and *electrical* engineering (low power/voltage vs. high power/voltage?).

Comment: Power distribution vs. electronics is a legitimate distinction, but I don't think "electrical" is the right term for that here.

Comment: TLDR; this "electrical" tag is as useful as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software would be on SO.

Comment: @AdamHaun: Correct. For power distribution we have [[power-distribution]]. And for power transmission, we have [[power-transmission]].

Answer (score 4):

I've looked at this on and off over the past week. Now, I count approximately 10 questions with the single [electrical] tag, and some of these questions are very poor - they should be easy to deal with.

I think the tag is safe to remove. The untagged remainder can be cleaned up pretty quickly.